# Finding the Count of Columns in Sql server under different conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008

Below query will give me publication count for each library

```
Select lib.Name, COUNT(pub.Id) From Library lib
INNER JOIN Publication lib.ID = pub.FK_Library_Id
```

But, In publication table, I have Free publications and Paid Publications and I want the count of Paid Publication and Free publications as well.

The below query gives me the result

```
Select lib.Name, COUNT(pub.Id), COUNT(pub1.Id) as 'Paid Publication COunt', 
COUNT(pub2.Id) as 'FreePublication COunt'
 From Library lib
INNER JOIN Publication pub ON lib.ID = pub.FK_Library_Id
LEFT JOIN Publication pub1 ON lib.ID = pub1.FK_Library_Id and pub1.Price > 0
LEFT JOIN Publication pub2 ON lib.ID = pub2.FK_Library_Id and pub2.Price =0
```

BUt this is at the cost of adding two more JOINS, which is not optimised.

How can i write the above query in a more effective and optimised way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use a SUM with CASE statement, as follows:

```
Select lib.Name, COUNT(*),
SUM(CASE WHEN pub.Price > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Paid Publication COunt', 
SUM(CASE WHEN pub.Price = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'FreePublication COunt'
 From Library lib
INNER JOIN Publication pub ON lib.ID = pub.FK_Library_Id
Group By lib.Name
```